# How to get rid of a ghost scrollbar (a white bar) in full-screen mode in Preview.app?

Tags: pdf, scrollbar, preview.app, macos-sierra

I am on macOS Sierra 10.12.1 and when I open a PDF file in Preview, switch to full-screen mode and hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> I get a white bar on the right end of my screen; the “Nobody Knows Shoes” PDF file [can be found here](http://evc-cit.info/cit020/nks.pdf):

[image: A PDF file in a Preview.app on macOS in full-screen mode. There is a white bar on the right end of the screen.]

In fact, there is a white bar at the bottom of the screen but it disappears when I move to another page.

There is no scrollbar in full-screen mode after pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> as the whole page fits the screen so it looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out that it is related to scrollbars. To hide it you have to go to *System Preferences* > *General* > *Show scroll bars:* and switch it to *When scrolling*.

I wonder if there is a way to hide it without modifying the system preferences. If so then I'll be happy to accept the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the scroll bar by default in Preview only, without changing the overall System Preferences, you can enter the following command in Terminal:

```
 defaults write com.apple.Preview AppleShowScrollBars -string WhenScrolling
```

That will set the preference only for Preview. To clear it again, so that it follows the general System Preferences, use this command:

```
defaults delete com.apple.Preview AppleShowScrollBars
```